# How to handle mixed data types in numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Stuck in this Numpy Problem

```
country=['India','USA']
​gdp=[22,33]

import numpy as np
a=np.column_stack((country,gdp))

array([['India', '22'],
       ['USA', '33']], dtype='<U11')
```

I have an NDArray and I want to find the maximum of the 2nd column. I tried the below

```
print(a.max(axis=1)[1])
print(a[:,1].max())
```

It threw this error: `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

Tried converting the type

```
datatype=([('country',np.str_,64),('gross',np.float32)])

new=np.array(a,dtype=datatype)
```

But got the below error

> could not convert string to float: 'India'.

Comment: Somebody edited your question please accept that. So, that we can review your question in more readable form.

Comment: I solved this using the below code

Comment: Now wait and keep an eye on your question, you'll be getting your answer as we speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the string data in your array, which makes the dtype to be Unicode(indicated by U11 i.e., 11-character unicode) string. 
If you wish to store data in the numerical format, then use `structured arrays`. 
However, if you only wish to compute the maximum of the numerical column, use

```
print(a[:, 1].astype(np.int).max())
// 33
```

You may choose to use other numerical dtypes such as `np.float` inplace of `np.int` based on the nature of data in the specific column.

Comment: But why did it create a unicode when my list is already float ? but in the array it gets converted to string ? WHy ?

Comment: Firstly, your list is not "float". If you create a numpy array from the list [22,33], the type will be int (as per the data values). Secondly, since you create the array from multiple lists, some of which consist of strings, the type of the resultant array will be string - in order to accommodate the different non-matching types.

Comment: Secondly, since you create the array from multiple lists, some of which consist of strings, the type of the resultant array will be string - in order to accommodate the different non-matching types    ...... How can we avoid such situation when creating array from multiple lists.

Comment: Structured arrays - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.rec.html address this.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `numpy` structured arrays for mixed types. You will have no issues if you *explicitly* set data types.

This is often necessary, and certainly advisable, with `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

country = ['India','USA','UK']
gdp = [22,33,4]

a = np.array(list(zip(country, gdp)),
             dtype=[('Country', '|S11'), ('Number', '<i8')])

res_asc = np.sort(a, order='Number')

# array([(b'UK', 4), (b'India', 22), (b'USA', 33)], 
#       dtype=[('Country', 'S11'), ('Number', '<i8')])

res_desc = np.sort(a, order='Number')[::-1]

# array([(b'USA', 33), (b'India', 22), (b'UK', 4)], 
#       dtype=[('Country', 'S11'), ('Number', '<i8')])
```

Comment: But I need a 2D array. these are two different output [('India', 22.) ('USA', 33.)]
[['India' '22']
 ['USA' '33']]