# Structured numpy array with 2 different data types

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I imported a csv file into a numpy array which I need to convert to a structured array with only the first column as dtype string and all the other 47 columns as float.
How do I define data type for the other 47 columns in a single operation? Do I have to specify dtype column by column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need numpy array for all the table? Would storing  each column in separate table be fine (then possibly creating a list from the column arrays)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359952/how-to-handle-mixed-data-types-in-numpy-arrays)

Comment: @JanStránský thank you for your reply. Yes, I need all the columns on the array. the first column is an identifier with duplicates and the other 47 columns are float numbers that I need to run complex calculations

Comment: Have you considered using pandas for storing the mixed data types data?

Comment: @FBruzzesi - I have to use numpy unless I can run a deap evolutionary algorithm using Pandas

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. I've found the solution. Just need to import from csv using genfromtxt specifying dtype=None and encoding=None. bm_array = genfromtxt(in_file, dtype=None, delimiter=',', encoding=None)

Comment: You might be happiest with two arrays, loaded separately with `usecolumns`

Comment: That `dtype=None` is a good general solution, though it would give you 48 fields.  An alternative is to specify a `dtype` like `np.dtype([('f0','U10'), ('f1', float, 47)])`.  This has just 2 fields, one with the string dtype, and the other a multielement float.  That could be better if you need to do calculations across those 47 columns.  `genfromtxt` is pretty good at constructing structured arrays, provided the total number of columns is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the source file just as a **structured** array.

Assume that you input file contains:

- one *string* field, to be named as *Id*,
- just **four** *float* fields, to be named as *F1*, *F2* and so on.

So its content is:

```
ABCD,160.72,180.21,260.13,451.48
EFGH,252.42,132.21,150.11,612.56
IJKL,541.77,455.21,268.76,543.81
```

To read such a file you can use *np.loadtxt* method, passing *dtype* as
a **structured** type (a list of definitions), which can be generated
e.g. in a list comprehension:

```
nFloats = 4
a = np.loadtxt('Input.csv', delimiter=',',
    dtype=[('Id', 'U10')] + [( f'F{i+1}', '<f4' ) for i in range(nFloats)])
```

Note that I passed *U10* as the type of *Id* column (10 chars).
If you need, set other size of this field.

The result is:

```
array([('ABCD', 160.72, 180.21, 260.13, 451.48),
       ('EFGH', 252.42, 132.21, 150.11, 612.56),
       ('IJKL', 541.77, 455.21, 268.76, 543.81)],
      dtype=[('Id', '<U10'), ('F1', '<f4'), ('F2', '<f4'), ('F3', '<f4'), ('F4', '<f4')])
```

Of course, in your target version of code increase *nFloats* accordingly
(probably it should be *47*).